# charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 603

Tags: python

File "D:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 603: character maps to

Answer (score 1):

you must use `encoding="utf-8"` when you are opening a file:

```
with open("filename.extension", "r+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
  # file.readlines()
  # file.read()
  # choose one of these
  pass
```

Comment: Already done on the initial script  as                                                                                                                              #######################################                                              
  devices_from_Excel = Extracting_data_from_Excel(Excel_File)
    global_row = 0
    print (devices_from_Excel )   
    book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
    sheet = book.add_sheet("ASR903_free_ports")